# How to send data use broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can get notification when BLE send me

The time is 50ms

I want to send data to BLE when I get broadcastreceiver

It can send a period of time(have callback)

But after a period of Time

Example  1 minutes

It can't send(can't get callback)

Why?

How can I do?

No one have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void sendBroadcast(String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra("key","data");
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Receive your data

```
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction() == yourAction){
                //Your code here
        }

        }
```

Comment: Now I must have a sendbroadcast?

Comment: Send broadcast to whome ?

Comment: I can get notification and the time is 50ms ,I use Google sample code so when I get notification I can get the ble send me data in broadcastreceiver what action is ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE,now I try writecharacteristic in here,

Comment: At the beginning write is fine,but a period of time ,the write not work ,notification always good

Comment: And my oncharacteristicwrite callback get the 133 status